# Continuation Object from Trigger

Tags: continuation

I have a requirement to invoke asynch Webservice callout whenever records is created or updated. I was planning to make a Continuation object callout form Trigger. But As I see in the documentation, it can be called only from Visualforce action method. Hence just wanted to know if it would be possible to make use of continuation object callout from Trigger, or do I need to play with Save button.

Answer (score 9):

You don't need to do either. Simply make a Queueable action that you call from the trigger to perform your callouts:

```
trigger XYZ on ABC (after insert, after update) {
    System.enqueueJob(new CalloutAction(Trigger.newMap.keySet());
}
```

And for the class:

```
public class CalloutAction implements Queueable, Database.AllowsCallouts {
    Set<Id> recordIds;
    public CalloutAction(Set<Id> recordIds) {
        this.recordIds = recordIds;
    }
    public void execute(QueueableContext context) {
        // Do your work here
    }
}
```

Note: This isn't necessarily full solution, because you're limited to 100 callouts per transaction, and a trigger may have up to 200 records. You may need to split the work across two or more Queueable objects, depending on what you're doing. If your endpoint supports bulk operations, this design may work just fine, however.

You can have up to 50 Queueable actions per transaction, so you can split your lists into chunks as small as four records each. Due to a limitation of Queueable, you can't currently callout-and-chain in the same Queueable method, so that's why you may need to split the items into multiple transactions.

Alternatively, you can use a normal Batchable method:

```
trigger XYZ on ABC (after insert, after update) {
    System.executeBatch(new BatchCallout(Trigger.newMap.keySet()), 10);
}
```

Which has a similar syntax, but is slightly more involved:

```
public class BatchCallout implements Database.Batchable<Id>, Database.AllowsCallouts {
    Id[] recordIds;
    public BatchCallout(Set<Id> recordIds) {
        this.recordIds = new List<Id>(recordIds);
    }
    public Iterable<Id> start(Database.BatchableContext context) {
        return recordIds;
    }
    public void execute(Database.BatchableContext context, Id[] scope) {
        // Handle callouts here
    }
    public void finish(Database.BatchableContext context) {
    }
}
```

Comment: I believe the Queueable  approach will not be suited as callouts are not supported in execute method however batch mode will work fine.

Comment: @manjit_singh You can use Database.AllowsCallouts to get callouts in Queueable. However, you cannot *chain* queueable methods if you callout.

Comment: Well, that was something I didn't knew

Comment: Thanks for the above suggestion, but out of curiosity I am trying to understand the following- My service takes about 10-15 secs to return sometimes. Also, all user will be updating the records very frequently. What is the governor limit for callout using Queueable Interface. Also, I need to display response to User.

Comment: @DeepSinghal The limits are shared with "batchable" classes and "future" methods: 250,000 calls per day (or 200 times user licenses), 60 seconds of CPU time (does *not* include callout time), 120 seconds callout time, 100 callouts per transaction, etc. Don't worry about hitting the limits, because you won't likely reach them with normal user usage, or even as a result of batch updates (in most usual cases). After performing your callout, you can save data back to the record the user can see. However...

Comment: @DeepSinghal ...you may just want to write a Visualforce page if you'd like to show the user some information immediately after the call. You can't just "override the save button" without writing an entire Visualforce page, and triggers can't perform a callout. This means you either use Visualforce and continuation methods, or you use Queueable/Batchable/future methods and you have to tell the user what happened later. You can't tie up the database with callouts, because you're explicitly disallowed from doing so.

Comment: @sfdcfox: Thanks a lot for the update. This is very very helpful